# No se como tomar el valor de un select

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5, phpmyadmin

Hola a todos necesito tomar el valor de un select el cual lo lleno con php, pero al momento de mandar las variables al archi php no me toma el select

```
            <select name = "congregacion" id = "cmbCongregacion"class = "input-100" required>
            <option value = "0">Escoga una congregación</option>
                <?php
                    $sql  = "SELECT cod_congregacion, nombre_congregacion FROM congregacion ORDER BY nombre_congregacion ASC";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['cod_congregacion'] ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre_congregacion'] ?> </option>'
                <?php
                    }
                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                    mysqli_close($con);
                ?>
        </select>



 <?php
include ("conex.php");
$cedula = $nombre = $apellido = $cmbCongregacion = $user = $pwd = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $cedula = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['cedula']);
    $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['nombre']);
    $apellido = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['apellido']);
    $cmbCongregacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['cmbCongregacion']);
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pwd']);
    $sql  = "SELECT cedula FROM hermanos WHERE cedula = '$cedula'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $active = $row['active'];
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($count >= 1){
        echo ("El usuario ya exite");
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        mysqli_close( $con);
    }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO hermanos (cedula, nombre, apellido) VALUES ('$cedula', '$nombre', '$apellido')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO hermano_congregacion (cod_congregacion, cedula, user, pwd) VALUES ('$cmbCongregacion', '$cedula', '$user', '$pwd')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        mysqli_close( $con);
    }   
}   
?>
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name = "congregacion" id = "cmbCongregacion"class = "input-100" required>
        <option value = "0">Escoga una congregación</option>
            <?php
                $sql  = "SELECT cod_congregacion, nombre_congregacion FROM congregacion ORDER BY nombre_congregacion ASC";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
            ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['cod_congregacion'] ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre_congregacion'] ?> </option>'
            <?php
                }
                mysqli_free_result($result);
                mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
    </select>
```

Para recoger el select tienes que hacerlo por medio del **name**, no del **id**

Prueba asi:

```
 <?php
include ("conex.php");
$cedula = $nombre = $apellido = $cmbCongregacion = $user = $pwd = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $cedula = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['cedula']);
    $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['nombre']);
    $apellido = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['apellido']);
    $cmbCongregacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['congregacion']);
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pwd']);
    $sql  = "SELECT cedula FROM hermanos WHERE cedula = '$cedula'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $active = $row['active'];
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($count >= 1){
        echo ("El usuario ya exite");
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        mysqli_close( $con);
    }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO hermanos (cedula, nombre, apellido) VALUES ('$cedula', '$nombre', '$apellido')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO hermano_congregacion (cod_congregacion, cedula, user, pwd) VALUES ('$cmbCongregacion', '$cedula', '$user', '$pwd')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        mysqli_close( $con);
    }   
}   
?>
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono, pero por que no funcionó de la manera que lo tenia si estaba tomándolo por el id???

Comment: Nunca me he preguntado eso, indagare.